# Do I need to do biometrics again?

Tags: visas, usa

I did biometrics for the first time in 2015 for an H-1B visa. I am applying for an O3 visa this time. Do I need to do biometrics again?

Comment: O3 is a dependent visa for the US.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll give biometrics every time you apply for a US visa if you are between 14 and 79 years old. You do this at the visa interview at the consulate; you do not need to make a separate appointment or pay any additional fee.